# Pandas apply on a column returning values for two columns on a portion of df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` and I want to apply a function to a column of the dataframe (`c3`) such that it returns values for two other columns (`c1` and `c2`), and this should be done only on a portion of the df rows.

I would have expected this to work:

`df.loc[0:20, ['c1','c2']] = df.loc[0:20, 'c3'].apply(my_f)`

where `my_f` is the function to be applied, returning a Series with the two values for `c1` and `c2`,

but it doesn't, the values for `c1` and `c2` remains `NaN` in `df` after executing this, despite no error or warning is raised.

What is the correct way to do this? It should be trivial, but I'm struggling to find it

For instance with the following code:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame([{'C3':1}, {'C3': 2}, {'C3': 3}, {'C3': 4}, {'C3': 5}, {'C3': 6}])

def my_f(s):
  return pd.Series(['V1', 'V2'])

df_test.loc[0:1, ['C1', 'C2']] = df_test.loc[0:1, 'C3'].apply(my_f)
df_test.loc[3:4, ['C1', 'C2']] = df_test.loc[3:4, 'C3'].apply(my_f)
```

the result is the following:

```
    C3  C1  C2
0   1   NaN NaN
1   2   NaN NaN
2   3   NaN NaN
3   4   NaN NaN
4   5   NaN NaN
5   6   NaN NaN
```

while I expect the following:

```
    C3  C1  C2
0   1   'V1' 'V2'
1   2   'V1' 'V2'
2   3   NaN NaN
3   4   'V1' 'V2'
4   5   'V1' 'V2'
5   6   NaN NaN
```

**NB: it is important taht I can do the assignments in separate instructions, as in the example above, since trying to do them all together makes me consume too much ram, crashing, due to the large size of my dataframe**

Comment: Please add a reproducible code example, with your attempt along with the data and your expected result, this makes it easier to see the potential error.

Comment: @DigitalFarmer I think it's already pretty clear, but I will try to improve it with a specific example

Comment: Without seeing the data model you're working with (a basic DataFrame example would be enough), it's a little tricky to be sure of the right approach to help.

Comment: @DigitalFarmer now it should be more clear, evenf if it's a very minimal example

Comment: What is a `progress_apply`?

Comment: @BeRT2me just the apply of tqdm, showing a progress bar, in effect it is not relevant for this question, I will replace it with `apply` in the code

Answer (score 1):

Try without `.loc` at the left assingment:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame([{'C3':1}, {'C3': 2}, {'C3': 3}, {'C3': 4}, {'C3': 5}, {'C3': 6}])

def my_f(s):
    return pd.Series(['V1', 'V2'])

idxs = [0,1, 3, 4]
# Or if you want to use different ranges
# idxs = list(range(2)) + list(range(3,5))

df_test[['C1', 'C2']] = df_test.loc[idxs, 'C3'].apply(my_f)
print(df_test)
```

---

```
   C3   C1   C2
0   1   V1   V2
1   2   V1   V2
2   3  NaN  NaN
3   4   V1   V2
4   5   V1   V2
5   6  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: It works, but I don't get why. Or better, I suppose it is able to deal with the two different dimensions of the return from the right hand side and the df on the left, but still I don't get why it does not work with .loc, which typically is the right way to effectively change the df

Comment: @Vitto, in your assigments in `.loc`, you pass indexs to `.loc` but you can not pass `index` you can pass a boolean list to `.loc`. you can read [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) : A boolean array of the same length as the axis being sliced, e.g. [True, False, True].

Comment: I've just realized that your solution is still now working in they way I need it, since it puts to nan everything that is outside [0:2], but I would like to keep it as it was, in the way that I can repeat the assignment on different subsets of df with different instructions and have all the values of c2 and c1 that I've inserted at the end

Comment: @Vitto, edited the answer, Is this what you want?

Comment: The problem is that I would like to be able to do it in separate instructions, for a very trivial reason: since my data frame is really big, colab crashes going out of ram if I provide it with all the indexes together, so I am doing it in a sort of batched way, one chunk of indexes after the other

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating things, or not explaining enough of what you're actually trying to do:

```
df_test.loc[(0, 1, 3, 4), ('C1', 'C2')] = ['V1', 'V2']
```

Output:

```
   C3   C1   C2
0   1   V1   V2
1   2   V1   V2
2   3  NaN  NaN
3   4   V1   V2
4   5   V1   V2
5   6  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but doing in this way, while theoretically working, makes me crash due to the large size of the dataframe. (And obviously `my_f` is not really returning constant values in my real code). The solution I have found for other operations is to work on the dataframe chunk by chunk, where a chunk is a portion of the rows which is not too large, so to avoid crashes